# Is a quadratic term inside a square root equivalent to a linear term?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

For a function such as
$$f(x) = \sqrt{x^2+a^2}, $$
is it correct to say it is *linear* in $x$?

Can I assume it can be written as $f(x) = \alpha x + \beta$ for some $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

EDIT: what if $x$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ may be matrices?

Comment: It can't be rewritten as a linear function (more correctly an affine function like $y=mx+b.$) To see why, square $mx+b$ and compare to $x^2+a^2.$

Comment: Extending the comment of @coffeemath, personally, I associate regarding a function $f(x)$ as linear as indicating that there is some constant $k$ such that $f'(x) = k$.  That is not the case with the function in your query.

Answer (score 3):

Take the first derivative of $f(x)$:

$$ f'(x) = \dfrac{2x}{2(x^2+a^2)^{0.5}}$$

If $f$ is linear in $x$, it implies that the first derivative must be a constant. We see that $f'(x)$ is not a constant, depends on $x$.

Comment: Good answer for a new contributor +1

Answer (score 2):

No not exactly. Though the function you have becomes more and more linear as $|x| \to \infty$. This is because as $|x| \to \infty$ the $+a^2$ becomes more and more "irrelevant". In particular, the function approaches $f(x) = |x|$ as $|x| \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Does it hold that $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$?

Comment: Definitely the best answer, used a vital property of what makes a function linear +1

Comment: Except that $f(x) = \alpha x + \beta$, which in precalculus and calculus is called "linear", doesn't have that property.  How about $f(x+y) - f(x) = f(z+y) - f(z)$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not linear in $x$.  A glance at a graph should convince you of that.

Comment: unless $a$ is 0 of course

Comment: or does $|x|$ not count as a linear function?

Comment: @SomeGuy $|x|$ isn't of the form $\alpha x + \beta$ which the OP mentions.

Comment: @coffeemath right